# seaborn plot a numpy matrix with color

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn

I want to plot a 3D matrix using the first column as the x coordinate, second as the y coordinate and the third column as the color.

So I tried it simply like this:

```
scat=np.matrix([[0,1,2],[10,11,12],[20,21,22]])

ax = sns.scatterplot(data=scat)
```

[image]

Buf for some strange reason instead of scatterplotting it, it plots it like a line plot on the x axis from left to right (from 0 to 2) for each row of data.

So how can I plot matrices how I described using seaborn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this works?

```
scat  =np.array([[0,1,2],[10,11,12],[20,21,22]])
a  =scat.T
a  =pd.DataFrame({'x':a[0], 'y':a[1] , 'z':a[2]})
ax =sns.scatterplot(data=a, x='x', y='y', hue='z',palette="deep")
```

edit: you can use palette , you can refer https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html or https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_visualization/seaborn_color_palettes/

Comment: yep it does, thanks, unfortunately it gives me really crappy colors:https://i.imgur.com/WwgkMNS.png

Comment: you can try different palettes , and choose which suits you most.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use seaborn's `scatterplot()` if you are not using dataframes and if you don't need the functionality that it provides. Use matplotlib's [`scatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html?highlight=scatter#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter) directly instead.

PS: np.matrix seems to be [deprecated](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html?highlight=matrix#numpy-matrix), use np.array instead.

```
scat=np.array([[0,1,2],[10,11,12],[20,21,22]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(np.squeeze(scat[:,0]), np.squeeze(scat[:,1]), c=np.squeeze(scat[:,2]))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks , that works. But the colors are terrible, yours are much better:https://i.imgur.com/qpRkOE6.png

Comment: You can change the colors by changing the colormap (see `cmap=` parameter). See https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html?highlight=colormap

Comment: thanks. I personally prefer seaborn though, it just kind of easier to work with when it works. Even comes with a legend by default